# how to export data to pdf in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i want to create a pdf in vuetify with image format more or less, this is the data that i need to insert in the pdf file:

[image]

[image]

my problem is how can i create the tables the labels and the others things?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert all your data to html and then use a npm package like [vue-html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf) and convert the html code to a pdf

Comment: i download the example but when i run yarn serve i get this error: "error Command "serve" not found."